# How to set the displayed title of a today extension in Yosemite

Tags: widget, osx-yosemite

What is the setting for changing the title in a today extension in Yosemite?
When Creating the target I chose something like "MyExtension" but I would like the header of the extension to display e.g. "What's up today".

How do I accomplish this?

I tried setting the Bundle display name in the info.plist but the displayed title never changed.
I suspect that many aspects of the widgets are heavily cached as well, which makes it really hard to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

The values in "**InfoPlist.strings**" supersede any setting in Info.plist.

Therefore the String for the key "*CFBundleDisplayName*" is displayed.

I guess, if there was no localization support in the project (is that even possible with a target of 10.10?) setting the bundle display name within Info.plist would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

from the target select info and under the info tab: bundle name(for app), and bundle display name(for extension)

Comment: I changed both, but neither has any effect.